# Activate blocks according to user selected number in Html

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a simple web page where a user selects number of friends and according to the input , invisible boxes are triggered , like if user selected 3 , 3 boxes will appear where user enters the friends name. I have made the Html code , but only 1 box is appearing everytime. I'm pretty new in Html , any help will be appreciated.

```js
function CheckColors(val) {
  var element = document.getElementById('color');
  if (val == 'pick a color' || val == '1')
    element.style.display = 'block';

  elif(val == 'pick a color' || val == '2')
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';

  elif(val == 'pick a color' || val == '3')
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';

  elif(val == 'pick a color' || val == '4')
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';

  elif(val == 'pick a color' || val == '5')
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'>
  <option>How Many Friends Do You Have?</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" style='display:none;' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try to achieve the things dynamically instead making multiple `if...else` blocks.

-> Create a new div called `input-block`

-> Then make for loop as per the value selected from select box.

-> Create new input element.

-> Append every new input elements inside the input block.

Assign each input box a unique id like `input.id = friend-${i+1};` to get the reference unique.

```js
function CheckColors(val){
 const element = document.getElementById('color');
 const inputBlock = document.getElementById('input-block');
 inputBlock.innerHTML = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < val; i++){
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = `friend-${i+1}`;
    input.placeholder = `Friend ${i+1}`;
    inputBlock.append(input)
  } 

}
```

```css
#input-block input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
    <option>How Many Friends Do You Have?</option>  
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>

  <br /> <br />

  <div id="input-block"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

create a box container, and then create given number of boxes dynamically:

```js
function createBox() {

  const box = document.createElement("input");
  box.type = "text";
  box.className = "box";
  return box;
}

function CheckColors(val) {

  var element = document.querySelector('.box-container');

  element.innerHTML = '';

  console.log(val)

  for (let i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    element.appendChild(createBox());
  }

}
```

```css
.box-container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.box-container .box {
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  margin-right: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'>
  <option>How Many Friends Do You Have?</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div class="box-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have only `1` input element to show in your `HTML code`. After that, you need to change your `elif` for `else if` in the `if statement`.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("select");
  select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var val = select.value;
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
    if (val == 'pick a color' || val == '1') {
      element[0].style.display = 'block';

    } else if (val == 'pick a color' || val == '2') {
      element[0].style.display = 'block';
      element[1].style.display = 'block';

    } else if (val == 'pick a color' || val == '3') {
      element[0].style.display = 'block';
      element[1].style.display = 'block';
      element[2].style.display = 'block';

    } else if (val == 'pick a color' || val == '4') {
      element[0].style.display = 'block';
      element[1].style.display = 'block';
      element[2].style.display = 'block';
      element[3].style.display = 'block';

    } else{ 
      element[0].style.display = 'block';
      element[1].style.display = 'block';
      element[2].style.display = 'block';
      element[3].style.display = 'block';
      element[4].style.display = 'block';
    }});
```

```html
<select id="select" name="color">
  <option>How Many Friends Do You Have?</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="color" class="color" style='display:none;' />
<input type="text" name="color1" class="color" style='display:none;' />
<input type="text" name="color2" class="color" style='display:none;' />
<input type="text" name="color3" class="color" style='display:none;' />
<input type="text" name="color4" class="color" style='display:none;' />
```